# Looking for external monitor comparable to my MacBook Retina display

Tags: monitors

I am looking for an external monitor that is comparable to the Retina display on my late 2013 MacBook, can anyone suggest options or help as far as what specifications I should be looking for?

I am a programmer and would like two 27" 2560x1440 or one 34" 3440x1440.
The most important factor for me is that text appare very sharp. and that the screen coating doesn't make the screen look grainy or dull. 
I am not on budget (-:

Comment: Also....to the OP, you need to specify what screen size you are looking for, what your budget is, as well as what you will be using the monitor for.   Be aware, that you are not likely to find a glass screen on an external monitor.  To my knowledge, Apple is the only company that puts glass in their laptop displays, and I believe they exited the stand alone display market a while back.

Comment: I have flagged this to be reopened, with any luck, others will do so as well.

Comment: What is your budget? Do you have a min/max monitor size you want?

Comment: With whatever monitor you are going to go with, keep in mind that you want to use your Macbook's Mini-DP port for the signal, as the HDMI port is only version 1.4, so especially when going for 4k, Mini-DP comes in handy.